# How much energy will be created using this method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

If I built a platform 100 meters high and put a crane on it then used solar power grid to drive the crane motor. Then using a 40 foot shipping container l filled it with dried sand. Then using the crane lifted the container to the platform. Now how much energy do I create when the container is lowered back to the ground.

Comment: Hi! Did you attempt to solve it yourself? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Potential energy is equal to mass * gravity * height. 
Dried sand is 1600 kg/m3. 
40ft shipping container volumne equals 67.6 m3
So weight of shipping container (3.7 tons) with sand (108 tons) is around 112 tons say.
Gravity is 9.8m/s2
Height equals 100m

Stick em together...112000kg * 9.8m/s2 * 100 = 109760000 kg m2/s2 or around 110 MJ minus losses. According to my lord o'google, that is about enough energy for a typical american household for a day.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this dra_red much appreciated regards Peter